# How to submit dynamic file type with FormData() jquery and receive it in php

Tags: php, jquery, multipartform-data, form-data

For single file upload it's working fine, see below example

```
<input name="audio_preview" id="audio_preview" type="file">

var formData = new FormData();
var audio_preview = document.getElementById('audio_preview');
var audio_preview_file = audio_preview.files[0];
formData.append('audio_preview', audio_preview_file);
```

Now receive it in php

```
[audio_preview] => Array
     (
       [name] => bawa_sus-bawa_sus-10511_hifi.mp3
       [type] => audio/mpeg
       [tmp_name] => /customers/4/6/d/domain.com/tmp/phpUTkVgr
       [error] => 0
       [size] => 116737
      )
```

Above code is working fine, but now i want to submit dynamic file input     field, check below code

```
<input name="download_files[]" type="file">
<input name="download_files[]" type="file">
<input name="download_files[]" type="file">
<input name="download_files[]" type="file">

<script>
var allFiles = jQuery("input[name='download_files[]']");
 jQuery.each(allFiles,function(index, value){
    formData.append('download_files[]', value.files[0]);
 });
</script>
```

It sends below array

```
[download_files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ajax-loader.gif
                    [1] => already-subscribed-help.gif
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/gif
                    [1] => image/gif
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /customers/4/6/d/domain.com/tmp/phpnd9czo
                    [1] => /customers/4/6/d/domain.com/tmp/phpNC4BlI
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 19110
                    [1] => 7805
                )
          )
 )
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            processData: false, // Don't process the files
            contentType: false,
            success: function(s) {
                alert('files uploaded');
                jQuery( '.wordpress-ajax-form' ).each(function(){
                    this.reset();
                });
                jQuery("#sucess").show().delay(4000).fadeOut();
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert("An error occured files uploaded: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
```

How to submit files with FormData() using jQuery.

Comment: you can use `ajax` for that

Comment: I have already used ajax

Comment: _“It sends below array”_ – that is simply how PHP builds the $_FILES array if an array of files is send - nothing wrong with that! If anything, your PHP code that processes this data needs adapting (assuming it can’t handle that properly, and that’s the underlying reason for your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace jQuery code inside script tag above like

```
<script>
 jQuery.each($('input[name^="download_files"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
     formData.append('download_files[]', file);
 });
</script>
```